# PHP script to download a file does work properly for .txt files but not image or video files

Tags: php, file, download, http-headers, file-handling

I am having issues with downloading a file in php. I've got a folder with files outside my server root (for security reasons, but I dont think this might by the problem), and I am trying to download a file using the script below,

where `$_POST['path']` or `$filename` (after check) is the absolute path of my folder, like
`/home/username/storage/filename.extension`

and my server root path is `/home/username/www`

when I try to download a .txt file, everything seems to work fine - I can download it and open it.

However, when I downloaded an image or video file, none of the applications on my computer could open the file.
For .png it says that my file is not a PNG file, for .jpg it says it does not start with `0x0a 0x0a`, etc.

Everytime I've tried to download something, the **size** of the file in the folder from which I downloaded it was **equal to** the size of the file that I downloaded. But there is **something wrong with the format/contents of the file**.
I checked the files in the directory from which I am downloading, there is no problem with them. The problem is only with the downloaded ones, so for some reason my script does not download them correctly.

Maybe my headers are not correct? Or maybe there might be a problem with files above some size (my txt files are smaller than images.., but even a 300M video was downloaded in a couple of seconds)? (However, there is no error in apache error log.) Or what am I doing wrong, please?

```
if(isset($_POST['path'])) {
  //Read the filename
  //+there are some checks on the path, to make sure user does not download a file which I dont want him to be able to download, but I dont think that is important, because the .txt file is downloaded normally
  $filename = $_POST['path'];

  //Check the file exists or not
  if(file_exists($filename)) {
      //Define header information
      header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
      header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
      header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
      header("Expires: 0");
      header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($filename).'"');
      header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
      header('Pragma: public');

      //Clear system output buffer
      flush();

      //Read the size of the file
      readfile($filename);
      //Terminate from the script
      die();
  }
  else{
      echo "File does not exist.";
  }
}
else
  echo "Filename is not defined."
```

Comment: The above code works just fine for me.. Did you check permission of the files you try to download? www-data (or the user your webserver is running as) should have read permission to the file and execute permission to the directory.

Comment: yes, I checked the permissions, but the permissions were not the problem in my case.  if there was a problem with permissions on the folder, i would probably not be able to download the text file ;). I checked the permissions of each downloaded file too, but they were the some as the text file's, so there was no problem with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that calling the `ob_clean()` method before `readfile()` was helpful :),

for more information, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-clean.php

this works for me:

```
if(isset($_POST['path']))
{
//Read the filename
$filename = $_POST['path'];

//Check the file exists or not
if(file_exists($filename)) {


//Define header information
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate");
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header("Expires: 0");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($filename).'"');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
header('Pragma: public');

ob_clean();    //<----- I had to add THIS LINE

//Clear system output buffer
flush();

//Read the size of the file
readfile($filename);
//Terminate from the script
die();
}
else{
echo "File does not exist.";
}
}
else
echo "Filename is not defined."
```